# Filter query with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like this

```
Assigned_job|Assignedbyuser|Approve

8999        |co-admin1     |0

8888        |co-admin2     |1

7777        |co-admin3     |0
```

Now if I want to get only Approve = 1
I can simply use

```
where Approve = 1
```

and I will get this result

```
Assigned_job|Assignedbyuser|Approve
8888        |co-admin2     |1
```

and if I want to get

```
only Approve=1 but if Assignedbyuser='co-admin1' don't check Approve =1
```

the end result should look something like this

```
Assigned_job|Assignedbyuser|Approve
8999        |co-admin1     |0
8888        |co-admin2     |1
```

Comment: 1. Is Approve boolean? 2. What you "wanna get" is unclear. If you really meant `only [if] Approve=1` then if `Assignedbyuser='co-admin1'` then you could at best only not return the row. Please write an actual grammatical sentence. Or enumerate cases. Or write an `if` statement. If you don't bother to be clear about what you mean you can neither program it yourself nor ask for it to be programmed. (You can ask for guesses.)

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `AND` and `OR` conditions:

```
WHERE
    (AssignedByUser <> 'co-admin1' AND Approve = 1)
    OR (AssignedByUser = 'co-admin1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from table 
WHERE (CASE Assignedbyuser = 'co-admin1' THEN Assignedbyuser = 'co-admin1' CASE WHEN  Assignedbyuser != 'co-admin1' THEN  Approve = 1 END)
```

Try This.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Case** statement in where.........

```
WHERE CASE WHEN AssignedByUser <> 'co-admin1' THEN Approve = 1
ELSE AssignedByUser = 'co-admin1' END
```

Answer (score 0):

> only Approve=1 but if Assignedbyuser='co-admin1' don't check Approve =1

That is unclear. I suspect you want:

```
 where Assignedbyuser='co-admin1' or Approve = 1
```

Read about the two kinds of SQL `case` expressions, which are its analogues to the `if` expressions of other programming languages. There are also functions involving "if" in their names and/or definitions.